# What's the physical meaning of imaginary part numbers from Inverse Fourier transform?

Tags: math

I'm trying to use the Fourier transform to identify the noise within my sensor's raw data. If I only do DFT and InverseDFT, the output signals will only contain the real part numbers, the imaginary part numbers are all zeros. But if I set some frequencies' complex numbers to zeros(R=0, I=0) after DFT, the signals from InverseDFT will have both real part numbers and imaginary part numbers.

Apparently, this is not a good way to remove the noise of some frequencies by setting the complex numbers to zeros, unless the imaginary part of InverseDFT has a right explanation.

Comment: This question is probably better suited a different Stack Exchange site - possibly https://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the interpretation of mathematics rather than programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each base frequency the Fourier transformation yields two items of information: amplitude and phase. Amplitude denotes how strong that frequency is represented in your signal. It corresponds to the absolute value of the complex number, i.e. sqrt(a²+b²) for z=a+bi. The phase indicates at which points in time that frequency component has its peaks. That is encoded in the angle of the complex number. As a first approximation you can imagine a Fourier coefficient of a+bi as representing something like "a cos(kt) + b sin(kt)".

I wrote "first approximation" because the above is not quite true, as you found out yourself. DFT operates on complex number on both ends of the transformation. If all your inputs are real, but not aligned in phase, then your output will have a specific pattern of complex numbers such that the imaginary parts cancel out exactly. If I'm not mistaken and I read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Real_and_imaginary_part correctly then the coefficients k and N-k must have equal real and opposite imaginary parts if the original signal is real only.

This means that if you know for sure that your input is real, half of the coefficients can be derived from the other half. Many data representation formats make use of this and only store half the numbers.

Comment: Thx for your reply! When I found the definition equation in the Wikipedia page, I started to program to run a test data immediately. Then the puzzle found me. I really should have read the whole page.